# PHP базы данных

Tags: php, mysql, sql

учу php.
Вот код  вывода на экран из базы данных. В первой строке возникает синтаксическая ошибка. Не могу понять в чем проблема. Ошибок в названии переменных точно нет

```
<?php $kommen = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM 'comments' ORDER BY 'id'") ?>
<?php while($kom = mysqli_fetch_assoc($kommen)) { ?>

        <div class="komment">
          <img src="123.png">
          <div class="name"><?php echo $kom['name'] ?></div>
          <hr>
          <div class="message"><?php echo $kom['message'] ?></div>
        </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: в MYSQL названия столбцов и таблиц пишутся в обратных кавычках

Comment: А ошибки можно спокойно в гугл переводчик кидать и читать что там написано.....и уж тем более надо их приводить, а не заставлять других гадать что там за текст ошибки

Comment: @АлексейШиманский там ещё и `;` пропущена.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Действительно проблема была в обратных кавычках) Буду дальше знать, а то уже все перепробовал. А насчет загуглить ошибку - ничего не получалось, так как писало просто: Fatal syntax error on line ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php $kommen = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `comments` ORDER BY `id`"); ?>
<?php while($kom = mysqli_fetch_assoc($kommen)) { ?>

  <div class="komment">
    <img src="123.png">
    <div class="name"><?php echo $kom['name']; ?></div>
    <hr>
    <div class="message"><?php echo $kom['message']; ?></div>
  </div>

<?php } ?>
```